# Bad credentials in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm making an Symfony2 site but I got some problems making work the user authentification. The sign up form works great, but when I try to log in I got the "Bad credentials" error.

Of course I checked my database fields and set them to 255 char for a sha512 hash. I even tried to store password in plaintext, but I got the same error.

I'm using Symfony 2.6.4 and PHP 5.5.14 running on Mac OS. I found nothing that is working for me on the web or on this forum, so I hope you're gonna find what's the problem here :/

Here's my code :

```
#app/config/security.yml

security:
encoders:
    Pass10\PersonBundle\Entity\Person: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    person:
        entity: { class: Pass10PersonBundle:Person, property: username }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/user
        provider: person
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            login_path:  /user/login
            check_path:  /user/login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The routing file:

```
#src/pass10/PersonBundle/Resources/Config/routing.yml
pass10_person_login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: Pass10PersonBundle:Person:login }

pass10_person_login_check:
    path:     /login_check

pass10_person_logout:
    path:     /logout
    defaults: { _controller: Pass10PersonBundle:Person:logout }

pass10_person_signup:
    path:     /signup
    defaults: { _controller: Pass10PersonBundle:Person:signup }
```

And the user entity ( I just show the relevant code ):

```
/**
 * Pass10\PersonBundle\Entity\Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pass10\PersonBundle\Entity\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        $this->createdAt = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And here's the code persisting the user :

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($person);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($person->getPassword(), $person->getSalt());
$person->setPassword($password);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();
```

The loginAction in the controller:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request){
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    $person = new Person();
    $form = $this->createForm('login', $person);


    return $this->render('Pass10PersonBundle:Person:login.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        // last username entered by the user
        'last_username' => $session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

And the view

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block main_content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {{ form(form, {'action': path('pass10_person_login_check')}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code.  To get a better and faster response, can you break it down to what you believe is the relevant code?

Comment: Of course, it's updated !

Comment: can you share your login view and login action

Comment: @Baig > I updated my original post.

Comment: And what debug efforts have you undertaken so far, and with what results?

Comment: @CBroe > I checked that the problem was not coming from the hash/salt itself by saving password in plaintext (and setting the salt to an empty string )  which didn't change a thing on the result. After that I checked multiple times routing and the security.yml fileto be sure that I haven't made a mistake there, but again I did found nothing on there. After that I don't know what to do since I can't access to the login_check action  (symfony is handling it by itself).
So to conclude, saving the object seems to work as expected so the problem really seems to come from the login_check action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling your login form is not correct, looking at the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html) of symfony it says

*your job is to display the login form and any login errors that may have occurred, but the security system itself takes care of checking the submitted username and password and authenticating the user.*

and the requirements for username and password is as following as per the same documentation.

The form can look like anything, but has a few requirements:

- The form must POST to /login_check, since that's what you configured
  under the form_login key in security.yml.
- The username must have the name _username and the password must have
  the name _password.

Your login form seems to be missing `_username` and `_password`.
Try using the following code in your login view

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData) }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

I hope this helps.

Remember to change `{{ path('login_check') }}` to the one you have setup